# Angularjs - Can't catch $watch event

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, angular-material

I am trying to implement this directive into my code without much succces. [angular-material-fileinput](https://github.com/shuyu/angular-material-fileinput).

I followed the instructions from the github page and i added "lfNgMdFileInput" to my module dependencies, added the html tag in the HTML and everything works great except for one thing.

The way i am suposed to catch the data inputed in the fields according to the documentation is by using `$scope.$watch('lfFilesName',function(old,new){...})`.

The data gets processed by the directive just fine and everything is saved without problems in the directives $scope but the $watch event never gets triggered except for the moment it gets initialized.

Please let me know if there is anything i should add. The code itsself is this:

```
// the piece of html
<lf-ng-md-file-input lf-files="files02" lf-api="api02" multiple></lf-ng-md-file-input>

// the piece of js; PS: While the selected files appear on the directive scope, they don't appear in the scope of my controller, 
//  witch i guess is normal but it would still have to catch the watch event, right?
$scope.$watch('files02.length',function(newVal,oldVal){
  console.log($scope.files02);
});
```

Edit1: (Code Snippet)

```
<body  ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
<div ui-view layout="row" ng-style="checkHeightReq()">
    <md-tabs md-selected="selectedIndex"  md-dynamic-height md-stretch-tabs="always" flex="100" md-border-bottom="">
        <md-tab label="{{lang.uploadDocuments}}" ng-disabled="tabsDisabled.tab4">
              <div ng-include="'partials/tabUploadDocuments.html'" ng-controller="UploadDocCtrl"></div>
        </md-tab>
    </md-tabs>
</div>
</body>
```

Partials/tabUploadDocuments.html :

```
  <lf-ng-md-file-input lf-files="files01"></lf-ng-md-file-input>
  <lf-ng-md-file-input lf-files="files02"></lf-ng-md-file-input>
```

UploadDocCtrl:

```
angular.module('demo').controller('UploadDocCtrl', UploadDocuments);


UploadDocuments.$inject = ['$scope','LangVars','$mdMedia', '$mdToast'];

function UploadDocuments($scope, LangVars,$mdMedia, $mdToast) {
//unrelated stuff
 $scope.$watch('files02',function(newVal,oldVal){
                     console.log($scope.files02);
                 },true);   
 $scope.$watch('files01',function(newVal,oldVal){
                      console.log($scope.files02);
                  });

//unrelated stuff
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "While the selected files appear on the directive scope, they don't appear in the scope of my controller"? Are you using the `lf-ng-md-file-input` in a separate directive? `$watch` watches the properties of the `$scope` by default. If it's in a separate directive, you should pass it around. A little bit more context would be helpful.

Comment: No, i am not using the lf-ng-md-file-input in a seperate directive. I have a simple html file that contains the tag, it gets imported inside a angular material tag (<md-tab>) and the specific tab has its own controller where im trying to catch the $watch event. If you think it would be helpful, i can post a snippet of how my code is structured.

Comment: I edited the post with a few code snipets of how the code is structured if it might help.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems like that ng-include is not using the `UploadDocCtrl` controller. An easy way to test it is to put a dummy variable  on your scope in `UploadDocCtrl`, and try to display it in the `Partials/tabUploadDocuments.html`. I strongly advise you to use a directive instead of `ng-include` and use the `controllerAs` notation. It may result more code, but everything is explicit and it won't fail silently.

Comment: I did the test and it seems to have passed. I set up a function that throws a alert on a button and it worked without issues.

Answer (score 0):

Watch will work on the Model property. You can change your code to use 'files02' only (i.e. without length).

```
$scope.$watch('files02',function(newVal,oldVal){
                 console.log($scope.files02);
     });
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortanely that doesnt work. I tried without length also. The demo they provided works with .length also though.

Comment: have you define files02 property during control initialization?

Comment: Do you mean if i defined the files02 property into my controllers scope during initialization? If yes, i hadnt, i just tried it though and it does seem to have helped.

Comment: I edited the post with a few code snipets of how the code is structured if it might help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will fix your problem but still,
looks like Angular is not catching the change in scope however that object is changing in your code.
One possible reason can be that object you applying watch, might be changing out of the scope of Angular (for eg.. jquery modal, etc)

So if thats the issue then try using $apply

here's the snippet

```
//place this just after the line when you are changing $scope.file02
$scope.$apply(function() {
   $scope.file02;
});
```

then angular will catch it in $watch block

hope it helps

---

UPDATE :

```
$timeout(function(){
     $scope.$apply(function() {
       $scope.file02;
     });
});
```

Comment: The app crashes with the "Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress" error message when atempting that unfortanely.

Comment: how your file02 object getting change in angular?

Comment: Through the directive imported from github.

Comment: I am updating my answer, check snippet then

Comment: I applied the updated snipped but unfortanely it didnt help with catching  anything in the $watch function.